# Bitwise OR Texels in WebGL2 fragment shader

Tags: javascript, gpu, webgl, gpgpu, webgl2

I am attempting to use use WebGL2 for some GPGPU computations. A key component of this is setting the value of a texel to the bitwise-OR of itself and the new value computed in the fragment shader. Is there a way of applying this bitwise operation to each fragment instead of overwriting the value completely?

Here is the relevant code:

```
precision mediump float;
varying float id; // integer passed though the vertex shader, value is in range [1, 32].

void main() {
  if (id == 1.0) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0039, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  } else if (id == 2.0) {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0078, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  } else if (id == 3.0) {
    ...
  }
}
```

To clarify the desired behaviour, let's say the value of a texel that we are writing to is 0b01. I perform some computation in the fragment shader and write the value 0b10. I would like the result to be 0b11.

I know that reading and writing operations to a single texture are mutually exclusive, so I am wondering if there is a way to configure WebGL2 to *always* perform a bitwise-OR when writing to a texture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no bitwise-OR writing.  Typically you read from some texture, bitwise or in the shader, write to a new texture

BTW, webgl2 has signed and unsigned integer textures.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Oh well, on to plan B.

Regarding the unsigned and signed textures, yes I am aware of that. I am using the most common configurations and incrementally specializing it, it is very easy with WebGL to end up in a really bad state that is difficult to debug. Thank you for the reminder though!

Also I want to take this opportunity to thank you for webglfundamentals.org, I don't know what I would have done without it :)